# How to play .wav audio file with gstreamer on Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, gstreamer, wav, gstreamer-1.0

The [`wavparse` documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/wavparse/index.html?gi-language=c) provides this example to play a `.wav` audio file through the speakers on Linux with Alsa audio.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=sine.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! alsasink
```

I have tried to adapt this for use on Windows with the `wasapisink` or the `autoaudiosink`:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=1.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v filesrc location=1.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! wasapisink
```

Both attempts result in an error:

> ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0: Internal data stream error.

The full logs look like this:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw, format=(string)S16LE, layout=(string)interleaved, channels=(int)2, channel-mask=(bitmask)0x0000000000000003, rate=(int)44100
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../gst/wavparse/gstwavparse.c(2308): gst_wavparse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoAudioSink:autoaudiosink0/GstWasapiSink:autoaudiosink0-actual-sink-wasapi: The stream is in the wrong format.
Additional debug info:
../gst-libs/gst/audio/gstaudiobasesink.c(1117): gst_audio_base_sink_wait_event (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoAudioSink:autoaudiosink0/GstWasapiSink:autoaudiosink0-actual-sink-wasapi:
Sink not negotiated before eos event.
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I have tried with multiple `.wav` files from various sources. Always the same result.

I have confirmed that `autoaudiosink` works on my PC because both of these commands generated an audible tone:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v audiotestsrc samplesperbuffer=160 ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v audiotestsrc samplesperbuffer=160 ! autoaudiosink
```

I have also confirmed that `playbin` can play the file through my speakers, but this doesn't work for me because ultimately I will need to split up the pipeline a bit more.

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe -v playbin uri=file:///C:/1.wav
```

I am using gstreamer 1.18.0 with Windows 10. How do I play the contents of a `.wav` file through my speakers using a `filesrc` and `autoaudiosink`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `audioresample` before or after `audioconvert` too. Not entirely sure about current windows audio subsystems - but nowadays hardware tend to require a sample rate of 48000 hz. If the audio subsystem does not take care of it you need to take of it yourself.